# golang error in getting a package

Tags: ubuntu, go, package

While trying to download the package in golang in my project using this command
I go this error

/home$ **go get golang.org/x/oauth2/google**

#google.golang.org/cloud/compute/metadata

prashant/.go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/compute/metadata/metadata.go:55: unknown net.Dialer field 'KeepAlive' in struct literal

Tried searching on google and have updated my golang version as well.
but the error is still coming.
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the newest go. Try

> go version

In go 1.5.1 that I have net.Dialer has also member KeepAlive. In your version probably don't. You can check

> go doc net.Dialer

Comment: but i did sudo apt-get --upgrade golang in my ubnutu and it said 
my Go version is latest. So I have to do it manually?

Comment: @Prashant: yes https://golang.org/doc/install. The distri packages don't keep up with tools like this.